# PHP - strip URL to get tag name

Tags: php, url

I need to strip a URL using PHP to add a class to a link if it matches.

The URL would look like this:

```
http://domain.com/tag/tagname/
```

How can I strip the URL so I'm only left with `"tagname"`?

So basically it takes out the final `"/"` and the start `"http://domain.com/tag/"`

Comment: Are you always looking to match the last thing enclosed in `/`s? Will there always be a final `/`?

Answer (score 2):

For your URL

```
http://domain.com/tag/tagname/
```

The PHP function to get `"tagname"` is called [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename):

```
echo basename('http://domain.com/tag/tagname/');   # tagname
```

Answer (score 0):

combine some [substring](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and some [position finding](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) after you take the last character off the string. use substr and pass in the index of the last '/' in your URL, assuming you remove the trailing '/' first.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `substring` based answers, you could also use a regular expression, using [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split the string:

```
<?php 
$ptn = "/\//";
$str = "http://domain.com/tag/tagname/";
$result = preg_split($ptn, $str);
$tagname = $result[count($result)-2];
echo($tagname);
?>
```

(The reason for the `-2` is because due to the ending `/`, the final element of the array will be a blank entry.)

And as an alternate to that, you could also use `preg_match_all`:

```
<?php 
$ptn = "/[a-z]+/";
$str = "http://domain.com/tag/tagname/";
preg_match_all($ptn, $str, $matches);
$tagname = $matches[count($matches)-1];
echo($tagname);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all, this code works for me:

```
$ptn = "/\//";
$str = "http://domain.com/tag/tagname/";
$result = preg_split($ptn, $str);
$tagname = $result[count($result)-2];
echo($tagname);
```