# PHP: Parse Current URL

Tags: php

I can catch current URL by `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which is `/mysitw/project/detail/fp/3` & want to parse like

```
array(0=>mysite, 1=>project, 2=>detail, 3=>fp, 4=>3)
```

and then easily search my required value using `in_array()` which I can do if could parse url successfully in an array

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - strip URL to get tag name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373936/php-strip-url-to-get-tag-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this...

```
$array = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

your array should look like this...

```
echo $array [0]; // mysite
echo $array [1]; // project
echo $array [2]; // detail
echo $array [3]; // fp
echo $array [4]; // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_splits = parse_url($url);
$path = $url_splits['path'];

$each_elemts = explode("/",$path);

print_r($each_elemts);
```