# Remove Some Text From a String

Tags: php, string, variables, gravity

I have a PHP variable that outputs some text on the page i.e. here's the text it outputs

`http://URL.com/uploads/gravity_forms/3-464e6bdac9890814218993b7e45c1736/2013/01/hehehecsv10.csv`

I would like to remove everything from this text and only show hehehecsv10.csv , how would I go about doing this in PHP

Comment: http://php.net/basename <- see here.

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is called [`basename()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/basename):

```
$string = 'http://URL.com/uploads/gravity_forms/3-464e6bdac9890814218993b7e45c1736/2013/01/hehehecsv10.csv';
echo basename($string); # hehehecsv10.csv
```

Output is as commented, [try the demo](http://eval.in/5874) if you need to play around with it.

See as well a somehwat related question:

- [PHP - strip URL to get tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3373936/367456)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'http://URL.com/uploads/gravity_forms/3-464e6bdac9890814218993b7e45c1736/2013/01/hehehecsv10.csv';

echo end(explode("/",$str));
echo basename($str);
```